# Keep certain elements in a list of tuples where condition is met

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples like this:

```
my_list = [('a','Yes'),('a','No'),('b','No'),('b','No'),('c','No'),('c','Yes')]
```

If there is a 'Yes' in either of the letter a, b, or c, then keep the tuple with 'Yes'. Otherwise just leave the tuple with 'No'.

In other words, how do I get the following output:

```
new_list =  [('a','Yes'),('b','No'),('c','Yes')]
```

I tired:

```
new_list=[]
for i,j in my_list:
    if 'Yes' in j:
        new_list.append((i,j))
# [('a', 'Yes'), ('c', 'Yes')]
```

But this only includes the tuples with 'Yes', I don't know how to include the one with 'No'.

Thanks

Comment: I think that you want to remove the repeated tuple ?

Comment: For letter b, yes. Since it has two 'No'. For other letters, I want to keep the one with 'Yes'.

Comment: @Iwishworldpeace : does n't `new_list`  in your question should n't be  `new_list =  [('a','Yes'),('b','No'),'b','No'),('c','Yes')]` to reflect your last comment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a very concise way to achieve this:

```
list(dict(sorted(my_list)).items())
# [('a', 'Yes'), ('b', 'No'), ('c', 'Yes')]
```

The sorting will put all `"No"` before the `"Yes"` for every unique first element. With the last value "winning" for every key and keys being unique in a `dict`, you will observe the desired behaviour.

Comment: yeah. LOL. well, I guess I am still not familiar with python. This is the best answer.

Comment: This is a very concise solution, otherwise it relies on the incidental property that "Yes" comes after "No" in the alphabet, not on the rule that affermative takes precedence on negative. For example, in German it would not work. In any case, as I stressed, it is a nice concise solution, +1

Comment: @nikeros You could still make it work with a little extra code for a custom sort key in German, `key=lambda p: (p[0] , p[1] == "Ja")`, but it's true, the full-scale brevity of this particular one is incidental.

Answer (score 2):

```
my_list = [('a','Yes'),('a','No'),('b','No'),('b','No'),('c','No'),('c','Yes')]
new_list = []
for i in my_list:
    if (i[0],'No') not in new_list:
        new_list += [(i[0],'No')]
        for j in my_list:
            if i[0] == j[0] and j[1] == 'Yes':
                new_list.remove(new_list[-1])
                if (i[0],'Yes') not in new_list:
                    new_list.append((i[0],'Yes'))
```

**Output :**

```
[('a', 'Yes'), ('b', 'No'), ('c', 'Yes')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could feed the sorted list to a dictionary constructor.  This will keep the last Yes/No for each letter.  The string 'Yes' being greater than 'No' will cause the letter to get a 'Yes' value if there is at least one.

```
new_list = [*dict(sorted(my_list)).items()]

print(new_list)
[('a', 'Yes'), ('b', 'No'), ('c', 'Yes')]
```

You could also do it without sorting by overriding the dictionary keys from all items with only those that have a 'Yes':

```
new_list = [*dict(my_list+[t for t in my_list if t[1]=='Yes']).items()]
```

If you must do it iteratively, you could go track the letters you added in the first loop (in a set), and go through my_list a second time after to add the missing letters (which will be the 'No' only tuples):

```
new_list = []
seen     = set()
for i,j in my_list:  # First add the 'Yes' tuples
    if j=='Yes' and i not in seen:
        new_list.append((i,j))
        seen.add(i)              # Track the letters added
        
for i,j in my_list:  # Then, add the missing letters ('No')
    if j=='No' and i not in seen:
        new_list.append((i,j))
        seen.add(i)              # Track to add only once
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [('a','Yes'),('a','No'),('b','No'),('b','No'),('c','No'),('c','Yes')]
new_list=[]
for x in range(0,len(my_list)-1):
    i = my_list[x][0]
    j = my_list[x][1]
    m = my_list[x+1][0]


    if i == m:
        if j == "Yes":
            new_list.append(my_list[x])
        else:
            new_list.append(my_list[x+1])

print(new_list)
```

This will give you desired output :)

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite the loop as:

```
my_list = [('a','Yes'),('a','No'),('b','No'),('b','No'),('c','No'),('c','Yes')]
res = {}
to_update = ["No", ]
for k, v in my_list:
    if (k not in res) or (res[k] in to_update):
         res[k] = v
```

Comment: You could improve on this solution :  `(res[k] in to_update)` could be simplified to `(res[k] == 'No')`  and `to_update` can then be suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution :

1. Iter on the list to build a dictionary in which values count the 'yes' and 'no'
2. Iter on the dictionary to build the result

```
my_list = [('a','Yes'),('a','No'),('b','No'),('b','No'),('c','No'),('c','Yes')]

# Iter on the list to build a dict in which values count 'yes' and 'no'
dcount = dict()
for k, v in my_list:
    # 'setdefault' is used to initialize new 'dcount' elements
    dcount[k][v] = dcount.setdefault(k, {'Yes':0, 'No':0})[v] + 1

# Iter on tmp to build the result
# 'bool' is used to reduce v['Yes'] to 0 or 1
new_list = [(k, ('No','Yes')[bool(v['Yes'])]) for k, v in dcount.items()]
```

then

```
print(new_list)
```

gives

```
[('a', 'Yes'), ('b', 'No'), ('c', 'Yes')]
```